# How to use Chai to simulate clicking on a hidden element?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, chai, e2e-testing

I am writing some simple e2e test for the website.

There is a hidden overlay on the website, this is what I did in the Chrome console and it worked.

[image: console]

And in my code, I have something like below:

```
it('v3::projects should be runnable', () => {
    const element = browser
      .executeAsync((done) => {
        done($(`.project-list #app${window.Project.first().cid} .card .overlay .icons a`)[0])
      })

    const result = browser
      .url('/workspace/apps')
      .click(element)
      .waitForVisible(`#simulator-wrapper`, 6 * 1000)

    return expect(result).to.be.true
  })
```

It always said

```
v3 runnable v3::projects should be runnable:
selector needs to be typeof `string`
running chrome
Error: selector needs to be typeof `string`
    at Promise.F (node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_export.js:35:28)
    at element([object Object]) - click.js:12:17
    at click([object Object]) - at Context.it (__tests__/e2e/v3_runnable.spec.js:47:8)
```

I think my selector is indeed a string and it works in my browser...

Would someone please point out what's wrong with the code? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted has a grave (`) instead of a single quote (') around the CSS selector. Try replacing the grave with ' and that should solve it.

Comment: It seems that ES6 features are not supported well here... Thanks!

Comment: I tried `done($('.project-list #app' + window.Project.first().cid + ' .card .overlay .icons a')[0])` but it still didn't work

Comment: I have figured it out. The first problem is what you mentioned in the answer. Another one is the element are hidden and not visible, so I need to control the mouse to hover on the element. I have solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it.